# How to align text including hidden elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

May I know how to make this align?

Line number 1 is hide the asterisk.
How to make the asterisk even hide will occupied width?

Sample code

```
<tr>
<td>
    <span width="10px" class="required" style="display: none;"%>Required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="param" size="40" name="fullName" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <span width="10px" class="required"%>Required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="param" size="40" name="fullName" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Thank

Comment: Do you want to do it with jQuery? Or just html?

Comment: JQuery as selector, html is the display.

Answer (score 4):

Then use

```
$('selector').css('visibility','hidden');
```

It will hide the content and leave the space.

Comment: Not yet. When I try to select the .required.

alert($(".required:visible").size());

Result showed 2.
The reason why I use hide() because it for above selection.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
input{
    float:right
}
span{
    float:left
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jRH95/)**

**OR**

`style="visibility:hidden;"` instead of `style="display:none"`

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jRH95/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `display:none`, use `visibility:hidden`.

You don't need jQuery for it, just change it on the HTML

```
<tr>
<td>
    <span width="10px" class="required" style="visibility: hidden;"%>Required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="param" size="40" name="fullName" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <span width="10px" class="required"%>Required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="param" size="40" name="fullName" value=""/>
</td>
</tr>
```

[LIVING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uSawQ/)